# Trouble installing MFSelector R package

Tags: r, bioinformatics, r-package

I cannot install the `MFSelector` R package. I tried the troubleshooting, but it is not working. Even the website is not accessible. Here is what I tried:

```
download.file("http://microarray.bmi.nycu.edu.tw:8080/tools/module/MFSelector/content/support/multicore/MFSelector_1.0.tar.gz", "MFSelector_1.0.tar.gz")

install.packages("MFSelector_1.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

I get this error:

> download.file("http://microarray.bmi.nycu.edu.tw:8080/tools/module/MFSelector/content/support/multicore/MFSelector_1.0.tar.gz", "MFSelector_1.0.tar.gz")
> trying URL 'http://microarray.bmi.nycu.edu.tw:8080/tools/module/MFSelector/content/support/multicore/MFSelector_1.0.tar.gz'
> Error in download.file("http://microarray.bmi.nycu.edu.tw:8080/tools/module/MFSelector/content/support/multicore/MFSelector_1.0.tar.gz",  :
> cannot open URL 'http://microarray.bmi.nycu.edu.tw:8080/tools/module/MFSelector/content/support/multicore/MFSelector_1.0.tar.gz'
> In addition: Warning message:
> In download.file("http://microarray.bmi.nycu.edu.tw:8080/tools/module/MFSelector/content/support/multicore/MFSelector_1.0.tar.gz",  :
> URL 'http://microarray.bmi.nycu.edu.tw:8080/tools/module/MFSelector/content/support/multicore/MFSelector_1.0.tar.gz': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached